# How can I structure my Tester class for this JAVA project?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, project

this is the gist of the assignment: http://prntscr.com/lwbb1x

so earlier I figured out how the EmployeeNames part of the assignment, or at least I think I did. This is the EmployeeNames code:

```
   public static String[] convertName(String[] names) {
      for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
         names[i] = names[i].substring(names[i].length() - 2, names[i].length());
        }
      return names;
```

But I'm basically stuck on the Tester code. I know what I want but it's not working. Can anyone help me out? I've been scratching my head at this for hours now.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
      /*Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter 10 last names.");
      String input = scan.nextLine();
      */ (Ignore this, I wanted to try doing inputs, but couldn't even figure out how to work with them properly so I typed up sample last names for this.)

     String[] lastName = {"Jones", "Roberts", "Lee", "Chang", "Patel", "Park", "Anderson", "Liu", "Smith", "Lopez"};
     System.out.println(convertName(lastName));
    }
```

I like to see modifications to my code or a pseudocode structure because it helps me realize my mistakes best, but any help is crucial! Thank you in advance.

Comment: lol that is a ridiculous and far fetched scenario!

Comment: Could you please copy the assignment into the post? Or even better: summarize this part.

Comment: Very ridiculous indeed, but what can I do? haha-- also, I think Sandeep has helped me figure out my minor mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your were doing some minor mistake, here is working code as per your requirement -

```
class EmployeeNames {
    public static String[] convertName(String[] lastNames) {
        String[] formattedNames = new String[lastNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lastNames.length; i++) {
            formattedNames[i] = lastNames[i].substring(lastNames[i].length() - 1) + "."
                    + lastNames[i].substring(lastNames[i].length() - 2, lastNames[i].length() - 1) + "." + lastNames[i];

        }
        return formattedNames;
    }

}

public class EmployeeNamesTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lastNames = { "Jones", "Roberts", "Lee", "Chang", "Patel", "Park", "Anderson", "Liu", "Smith",
                "Lopez" };
        String[] formattedNames = EmployeeNames.convertName(lastNames);
        for (String formattedName : formattedNames) {
            System.out.println(formattedName);
        }

    }

}
```

> Output:
>   s.e.Jones
>   s.t.Roberts
>   e.e.Lee
>   g.n.Chang
>   l.e.Patel
>   k.r.Park
>   n.o.Anderson
>   u.i.Liu
>   h.t.Smith
>   z.e.Lopez

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thank you Pradeep, this is EXACTLY what I needed. I see how the usage of the enhanced for loop can come in handy here as well. Thank you so much for the straightforward help!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some logical mistakes in problem.

```
public static String[] convertName(String[] names) {
        String newNames[]=new String[names.length];
          for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
             newNames[i] = names[i].substring(names[i].length() - 2, names[i].length());
            }
          return newNames; 
    }
```

In above method i just create new array and return new array with modified values.

And in Main method following code is used-

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String[] lastName = {"Jones", "Roberts", "Lee", "Chang", "Patel", "Park", "Anderson", "Liu", "Smith", "Lopez"};

            String [] result= convertName(lastName);
            for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                String lastNames=result[i];
                if(lastNames !=null){
                    System.out.println(lastNames.toUpperCase().charAt(1)+"."+lastNames.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+". "+lastName[i]);
                }
            }

}
```

Hope this will help you.!!

Comment: This is also a really good method! Thank you Mostch, super appreciate this. I see my errors now a lot clearly.

Comment: Please accept answer and upgrade answer if this help.